# Year-Over-Year Data for last week

Tags: mysql, date

I am currently writing a query that will give me last weeks data (lets assume "SALES") and last years data for the same week. This is what I have to get last weeks data and it works fine:

```
Set DATEFIRST 1 
Select DATEPArt(dd, DateAdded) AS 'Day of the Month', 
       count(*)AS 'Number of Users'
from TABLE1
Where DateAdded >= dateadd(day, -(datepart(dw, getdate()) + 6), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
  AND DateAdded <  dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
Group by DATEPArt(dd, DateAdded)
Order by 'Day of the Month'
```

Now I want to add another column that will give me last years data from the same week. This is what I was thinking:

```
Set DATEFIRST 1 
Select DATEPArt(dd, DateAdded) AS 'Day of the Month', 
       count(*)AS 'Number of Users'
from TABLE1
Where DateAdded >= DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
  AND DateAdded < DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE())+1,0)
  AND DateAdded >= dateadd(day, -(datepart(dw, getdate()) + 6), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
  AND DateAdded <  dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
Group by DATEPArt(dd, DateAdded), DateAdded
Order by 'Day of the Month'
```

Problem is that I am still getting last weeks numbers (this year, I need it to be last year). This leads me to believe the error has to be here somewhere:

```
DateAdded >= DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
AND DateAdded < DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE())+1,0)
```

I appreciate everyone's help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an `OR` condition

```
WHERE (DateAdded >= DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
  AND DateAdded < DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE())+1,0))

OR (DateAdded >= dateadd(day, -(datepart(dw, getdate()) + 6), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
  AND DateAdded <  dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())))
```